# Change Logo, Icon of Chromium browser for windows

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, webviewchromium, chromium-portable

I want to change the GUI of chromium browser and rename it to make it my personal browser.
Any idea what should I do to change the images like it's logo, back and forward buttons, and other many icons. and I want to stop its google synchronization as well. to keep my browsing history and bookmarks private.

Comment: You will have to make lots of changes. The answer to your question is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Hi @Asesh .If you know can you guide me something or If you know someone who has done it before. I can ask that person